# "Delete row" button for MySQL in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, forms, html-table

I have a table that becomes populated with data from a MySQL database, and each row receives its own delete button.  I would like to have the option to delete each row separately with a delete button that deletes the corresponding row in the database.  How would I go about doing so?  Here's the part of the code that I have to far, which does not seem to work whatsoever.

```
if(isset($_POST['id'])) {
$id = $_POST['id'];
$delete = mysql_query($conn,"DELETE FROM mods WHERE id = '$id'");
}
```

Unimportant code omitted.

Table/Form Creation:

```
   echo "<td><form action=\"\" method=\"post\"></td>";
   echo "<tr class='modlist'>";
   echo "<td>".$row['id']."</td>";
   echo "<td><div class=\"edit\" id=\"div_1\">".$row['title']."</div></td>";
   echo "<td><div class=\"edit\" id=\"div_2\"><a href=".$row['mod_url'].">".$row['mod_url']."</a></div></td>";
   echo "<td><div class=\"edit\" id=\"div_3\">".$row['developer']."</div></td>";
   echo "<td><div class=\"edit\" id=\"div_4\">".$row['type']."</div></td>";
   echo "<td><div class=\"edit\" id=\"div_5\">".$v162."$nbsp".$v164."$nbsp".$v172."</div></td>";
   echo "<td><div class=\"edit\" id=\"div_6\">".$row['title'].",$nbsp".$row['developer']."</div></td>";
   echo "<td><div id=\"save\"><input type=\"submit\" name=\"save\" value=\"Save\"></div></td>";
   echo "<td><div id=\"delete\"><input type=\"submit\" name=\"delete\" value=\"Delete\"></div></td>";
   echo "</tr>";
   echo "</form>";
   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Form action needs to have a control with the name 'id', otherwise $_POST will not get any id.

You can do it like `<input type="hidden" name="id" value=".$row['id']." />`

Also, I suggest you have a look at [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) as your form, by the code you displayed, looks completely vulnerable.

**UPDATE**

You also have to fix your `$delete` query like nl-x mentioned:

```
$delete = mysql_query("DELETE FROM mods WHERE id = '$id'", $conn);
```

Comment: I added the line to the form, as well as everything said above, but still no luck deleting the row, any ideas?

Comment: I also used/added his changes but still no luck.  Is the form action empty with the code you provided or should I have something in it?  I currently have `action='".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']."'` which seems to do the same thing as a blank action in this case.

Answer (score 3):

You have the parameters for `mysql_query()` backwards. First pass the query, then pass the $conn.

```
$delete = mysql_query("DELETE FROM mods WHERE id = '$id'", $conn);
```

But beware you now have an SQL injection problem! Sanitize $id before you use it!

```
$id = mysql_real_escape_string($id);
```

And consider using `mysqli` or `PDO` (and use parameterized queries), as `mysql_*` are deprecated!

Comment: +1 for suggesting use of mysqli or PDO. You're better off learning (and using) this sooner rather than later.

Comment: @swiftsly Also look at the answer of Jerry. That is also important!

Comment: @nl-x Alright, I fixed the query, added the sanitization for `$id`, and change things over to mysqli, but it still doesn't delete the row.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This **WORKED**
I created the button with PHP code in my table
**table.php**

```
<?php 
include "connect.php";
$rezult = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT id,p1,p2,p3 FROM table");
if($rezult === FALSE) {die(mysql_error());}
$count=mysqli_num_rows($rezult);
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($rezult)){

echo "<tr><td>".$row['p1']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['p2']."</td>";
echo "<td>".$row['p3']."</td>";
echo "<td><form action='delete.php' method='post'><input type='hidden' 
value='".$row['id']."'><input type='submit' name='delete' value='DELETE'>
</form></td></tr>";
?>
```

**delete.php**

```
<?php

include "connect.php";
$str_del="DELETE FROM table WHERE (id=".$_POST['id'].")";
$result = mysqli_query($con,$str_del) or die (mysql_error());
?>
```

**connect.php**

```
 <?php
$dbhost = ""; // ip
$dbname = ""; // DBname
$dbuser = ""; // login
$dbpass = ""; // pass
$con=mysqli_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass, $dbname);
mysqli_query($con, 'CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `table');
mysqli_select_db($con,$dbname);
mysqli_query($con,"set names utf8");
?>
```